# How to make Screeps find sources?

Tags: javascript, screeps

In Screeps, I this code doesn't work:

```
var sources = creep.room.find(Game.FIND_SOURCES_ACTIVE);
```

It says this:

```
Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
```

I have been looking around and cannot find ANY other way to find sources.

Also I've noticed that most of other peoples code doesn't work and even the tutorial's code no longer works when put into the real game.

Comment: Can you provide more context? It's possible that `creep` might not even be an instance of `Creep` at all, which could be why `creep.room` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be completely sure about your issue since I don't have your complete code to go off of but one issue could be that `creep`is not defined.

You need somewhere in your code to define `creep` such as a for loop to loop over each of your creeps in the game or room.

```
var roleMiner = require('role.miner') // role.miner being the module name for miner actions
for(var name in Game.creeps) {
    var creep = Game.creeps[name];
    //
    // do whatever you wish with the current selected creep.
    // 
    // most of the time you will call a module similar to what the tutorials suggest and put your actions for it in there
    //
    if(creep.memory.role == 'miner'){
        roleMiner.run(creep);  // passes the current selected creep to the run function in the module
    }
}
```

So, in your roleMiner module you would have something that defines your miners actions.

```
var roleMiner = {
    run: function(creep) {
        // this one returns an array of the sources that are in the room with the creep
        var sourcesRoom = creep.room.find(FIND_SOURCES);

        // this one returns the source object which is closest to the creeps positon
        var sourcesClose = creep.pos.findClosestByRange(FIND_SOURCES);
    }
}
module.exports = roleMiner;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Screeps have some ... mechanism when sharing your data between each game tick.
If you store any thing in global Memory object, your data will lose all its prototype.
to restore your prototype use Object.setPrototypeOf(creep,Creep.prototype) or create new Creep object from your creep id.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
var sources = creep.pos.findClosestByRange(Game.SOURCES);
```

or

```
var sources = creep.pos.findClosestByPath(Game.SOURCES);
```

Comment: I just get this:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'findClosestByPath' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

im a new player, not sure my code is efficient, i think the find method will be like this:

`var sources = creep.room.find(FIND_SOURCES_ACTIVE)`

creep will going to the active resource to harvester.